# how to define define structure pointer and below mentioned format. and how to access .servicefunc in code?

Tags: c, pointers, structure

```
CONST(Student_ServiceCfgType, VAR) student[] =
{
    {&Student_Name,    NAME},
    {&Student_age,  AGE}
};

main_function()
{
   /* get the Service index of the Service Configuration table */
    Student_Service =  0; // takes 0th element from above config table.

    /* Send the service */
    status = (*student[Student_Service].ServiceFunc)();

    /* notify application about service finish */
    status = Student_UsrCallback(student[Student_Service].ServiceType, status);
}

struct
{
}Student_ServiceCfgType;


status = (*student[Student_Service]***.ServiceFunc***)();
```

Question1)  Please explain me what is meant by above line of code?

Q2) can explain how the above code works

Comment: You need to provide more information: following is not standard C: `STATIC`, `CONST`. Furthermore: What is `Student_ServiceCfgType`? What is `Student_Service`? What is `student`? What is `Student_UsrCallback`? etc. Please [edit]  your question and clarify. Also read this: [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*1. Please explain me what is meant by above line of code ?*

- `ServiceFunc` is pointer to function, which holds the address of function which returns `status` type and takes no arguments.

> So overall your `struct student` might look like below.

```
typedef struct
{
  status (*ServiceFunc)(); //declaring function pointer
}studentStruct;
```

> And you function might look like below.

```
status func1()
 {
      status ret = 0;
      printf("studenti\n");
      return ret;
 }
```

> And you assign the function pointer and call the function using function pointer as below.

```
studentStruct student[1];
student[0].ServiceFunc = &func1;

status st = (*student[0].ServiceFunc)();
```

that is what you are exactly doing here.

```
status = (*student[Student_Service].ServiceFunc)();
```

> Your complete code might look like below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef int status;

typedef struct
{
  status (*ServiceFunc)();
}studentStruct;


status func1()
{
  printf("studenti\n");
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
 studentStruct student[10];
 student[0].ServiceFunc = &func1;

status st = (*student[0].ServiceFunc)();

return 0;
}
```